# how to get coordinates from openstreetmap

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to get coordinates when I click on the map in order to put in the address field. I didn't know what to put inside my function to get information about the location!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var myMap;

function loadOpenLayers(){  

myMap = new OpenLayers.Map("mymap", {});

var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
"OpenLayers WMS",
"http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
{layers: "basic"},
{});

myMap.addLayer(wms);

myMap.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-122.349243, 47.651743));

myMap.zoomTo(6);   
myMap.on('click', function(event) {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";

});
} 

</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadOpenLayers();">
<div id="mymap" style="width: 620px; height: 460px; border: 1px solid;">
<p id="demo">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing should already return a Map event, which has a coordinate in your projection. Try something like this

```
myMap.on('click', function(event) {
   console.log(event.coordinate);
});
```

and check if you are getting the correct coordinates in the console.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getEventCoordinate

Comment: it did not work , nothing inside the function (myMap.on('click',function(event)) works ,i even tried to simply change the text of the paragraph (check the code i posted) also did not work , i am using javaFX and i need it for my Desktop application !

Comment: Sorry didn't see this was OL2.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up OpenLayers 2 and OpenLayers 3+ code.  `myMap.on('click', function(event) {` is OL3+.  If you must use OpenLayers 2 you need

```
document.getElementById("mymap").onclick = function(event) {
  var lonlat = myMap.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(event.clientX, event.clientY));
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lonlat.lon + ' ' + lonlat.lat;
};
```

but if you are starting a new project it would be much better to start again using the latest OpenLayers 5.

Comment: thanks it works ! now i am having a problem putting these informations to my address field ! i am working with JavaFX  trying to build a desktop application and i need the client to put his address using openstreetmap

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me :

```
myMap.on('click', function(e) {
 alert("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
});
```